# Loss function for comparing high-dimensional joint distributions

Tags: loss-functions, joint-distribution

I'm synthesizing data trained from a source dataset, and am looking for a loss function to compare different data synthesis methods*. I have some ideas below, but each has drawbacks and none is very elegant. Is there an established loss function to compare high-dimensional joint distributions?

Here are my ideas, but all look just at one variable at a time without considering the joint nature explicitly, so would have to be evaluated across strata.

- **MSE:** Just compares means, without considering distributions.
- **Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic:** e.g. an average of each summed. Doesn't consider the full distribution.
- **Deviations from quantiles:** e.g. for some set of equally-spaced quantiles. Captures more of the distribution.

Another idea could be something like cosine distance, matching each synthetic record with its nearest real record.

* The loss function could be zero when passed the real data, so I'm separately checking to ensure that no synthetic record exactly matches a real one. Though this might be unnecessary if comparing to a holdout set, given an ideal method would avoid overfitting.

Comment: Popular options for measuring distances between multivariate distributions include the [Wasserstein distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric), the [maximum mean discrepancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_embedding_of_distributions#Measuring_distance_between_distributions), and any of various [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) eg the [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). Can you give some details of what your distributions look like? (Continuous or categorical? How many dimensions, sample points?)

Comment: Thanks, the data is ~30 dimensions, almost all continuous and many being positive and roughly log-normal (though some negatives too). Original data has ~100k observations. I can share some sample points later tonight.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Also: to check, your synthesis methods just produce samples, no likelihoods or anything, yes? And do you have a particular defined task you want to use these samples for, or just generally want to match the distribution overall?

Comment: (I’ll write an answer overviewing what I think are likely the best options tomorrow, it’s late in my time zone but this is something I happen to know a bunch about. :) )

Comment: Yes, the synthesis methods produce samples, not likelihoods (though I'm looking at methods that generate likelihoods, from which I select randomly from the joint CDF). Context: this is to create a public dataset for tax analysis based on nonpublic data. The data would ideally produce similar estimated impacts of tax reforms as those calculated from the original dataset, something I intend to quantify in addition to the similarity of the datasets.

Comment: Some tools I've been looking at include the `synthpop` R package, rolling my own sequential random forest quantile model (variable-by-variable, similar to `synthpop`), and TensorFlow Probability. TF presumably uses some loss function, but I'm very early in exploring that so I don't really know how it could be applied, if at all.

Comment: I just realized it might make sense to compare the synthesized data to a holdout. Edited question accordingly.

Comment: [This notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_kOgXABRLWzvBl5LV2qJiHbFSEpbvEKe) shows sample data and some CDFs.